# Ajax call to consume rest service on local host

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, rest

Hi I have written a rest service using the Spring framework Below is the code.
It returns Json appropriately.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/showProcessUsage/" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public SystemProcessInfo getASingleProcessInfo()
{

    String processName="chrome" //hard coded just for trials;       
    SystemProcessInfo processInfo ;
    processInfo = processInfoService.getASingleProcessUsage(processName);
    return processInfo;
}
```

In the Html I am trying to make an ajax call, but it is failing 
below is the call

```
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept:"application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        url: "/PerformanceMonitor/showProcessUsage/",
        success: function(data){        
            alert("HI");
            alert(data);
           alert("HI");
        }
    });
```

Comment: How is it exactly failing? What does the console window show? What does the network window show?

Comment: can you post the error code in console??

Comment: It does not show any error.I was expecting the dialogue box to be displayed.But the page is blank.

Comment: You must be able to see the Ajax call in your firebug console.Can check in its details..

Comment: .I checked on debugging, it does not enter the ajax method.

Comment: It goes in till the breakpoint line type= "GET" ..but after that it goes soemwhere unknow  some "VM 677" something .. and never returns from there

Comment: put error block in your ajax call and put debug points within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thee js file for jquery that I included was corrupt .. I tried using the google cdn for jquery and it worked fine for me. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

There a  number of code issues where it could fail:

First, Your rest service endpoint expects a

```
@PathVariable("processName")
```

which I don't think you are passing in the AJAX call.

try with the following line

```
url: "/PerformanceMonitor/showProcessUsage/xyz-process"
```

Secondly, your Spring controller method should contain the pathVariable defined in the annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showProcessUsage/{processName}"
```

For debugging:

put an error block in your ajax call.

```
error: function(response){ 
            alert(response);
        }
```

Comment: I forgot to erase that out ... edited my question accordingly .. For the time being I have hrdcoded the process name instead of passing it via URL .Sorry for the typo.